# What are the 30 Mitzvot for Bnei Noach?

Tags: number, gentiles, noachide-laws

What are the 30 Mitzvot (Commandments) that Bnei Noach have accepted (based on [Hullin 92a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=92&format=pdf))?

> שלשים מצות שקבלו עליהם בני נח.‏
>     Thirty commandments which Bnei Noach accepted upon themselves.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Laws_of_Noah#Subdividing_the_Seven_Laws

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8481/603

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36448

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rabi Menachem Azaria from Pano says that the Thirty commandments is sections of the 7 commandments (עשרה מאמרות, מאמר חקור דין חלק ג פרק כא).

Rashi on the Gmara says that we don't know what is the list of the 30 commandments.

See also the [Talmud Yerusalmi](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r4702.htm) (מסכת ע"ז דף ט,א פרק ב הלכה א גמרא) that says in the future Bnei Noach get 30 commandments. Maybe this is the meaning of Ula.

Comment: Haim Evgi, welcome to judaism.SE and thank you for you valuable answer. I think, we learned together in JCT ;)

Comment: i learn in jct between 98 and 02

Comment: I've sent you invite on LinkedIn ;)

Answer (score 7):

R. [Shmuel ben Hofni Gaon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_ben_Hofni) lists the 30 mitzvot as follows:

א. עבודה זרה
ב. ברכת השם 
ג. יחוד השם 
ד. תפילה 
ה. שבועת שקר 
ו. הריגת אדם את עצמו 
ז. הריגת אדם את זולתו 
ח. אשת איש 
ט. עריכת נשואין על ידי מוהר ומתן 
י. האחות 
יא. משכב זכור 
יב. הרבעת בהמה 
יג. סירוס 
יד. נבלה 
טו. אבר מן החי החי 
טז. דם מן החי
יז. איסור כלאים בבהמות 
יח. חסר מכתב היד 
יט. קרבנות 
כ. גזל 
כא. כבוד אב ואם 
כב. מעביר בנו ובתו באש 
כג. קוסם קסמים 
כד. מעונן 
כה. מנחש 
כו. מכשף 
כז. חובר חבר 
כח. שואל אוב 
כט. ידעוני 
ל. דורש אל המתים

Source: Sinai, Vol. 72, p. 205. See also: ["Samuel ben Hophni's Noahide Law."](http://www.wikinoah.org/index.php?title=Samuel_ben_Hophni%27s_Noahide_Law)

Comment: Is Sinai a journal? I'm not familiar with it. Who publishes it?

Comment: Yes, published by Mossad Harav Kook.

Comment: IMO, this answer would be more valuable with a translation (as I don't think most curious Noahides can read Hebrew) .....but it [shouldn't be too hard](http://www.wikinoah.org/index.php?title=Samuel_ben_Hophni%27s_Noahide_Law) ;)

Answer (score 3):

"As Rashi (Rabbi Shlomo Yitzchaki) tells us, Chazal (the Sages) do not elaborate on the nature of the 30 commandments, but various commentaries offer suggestions. The basic thesis with which they work is that the 30 commandments are subdivisions of the seven Noachide commandments.

There are two versions of the 30 Noachide Commandments:

```
The  30 Noachide Commandments recorded by Rabbi Shmuel ben Hofni, Gaon.
The  30 Noachide Commandments recorded by Rabbi Menachem Azaria de Fano."
```

Both of these versions can be read here:

http://www.noachide.org.uk/html/30_commandments.html

Comment: This link no longer works.