# 420 Noachide Commandments?

Tags: number, mitzvah, noachide-laws

I know there are seven specific commandments to noachides but recently I was talking to a Rabbi who told me actually noachides have 420 commandments and the Jewish nation has 613. Can anyone point me to where I can find these 420 commandments he spoke of? Was he just making something up or is there somewhere I can read these? I am aware they are in the Torah but I would like to find them ordered if there is already a list someone is aware of.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16239/472

Comment: @MonicaCellio If that means as in the other post we can not know until the future he must be making them up?

Comment: Hi Yosi.  Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for bringing your question here.  I hope you enjoy the site (looks like you've been looking around already).

Comment: I linked the question mainly because it posits a number greater than 7 (though a much smaller number than the rabbi you talked with says).  I don't know if the leads there help at all, but I find cross-linking related questions to be useful.

Comment: I am following the related links on that thread as well as Wiki links. They are great, I may need to make this as answered.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Divine-Code-Volume-Expanded-Edition/dp/0981481167

Comment: Toda raba @Menachem we plan on buying those as well as the "Sefer Sheva Mitzvos Hashem" to help with these details :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember a PHD thesis (I think by Rabbi Lichtenstein, but I will have to find it) in which he stated that the 7 are actually categories, each of which consists of a number of different mitzvos (as far as making a link with the Torah goes). For example, there is the category of theft which can be broken down it individual mitzvos.

Comment: It would be an interesting exercise to take [Samuel ben Hophni's list of 30](http://www.wikinoah.org/index.php?title=Samuel_ben_Hophni%27s_Noahide_Law) and try and correlate how each of the 30 can be considered as inside one of the seven categories. For many of these 30, the correlation to the 7 categories is obvious, but I am not sure if it will work out for every one.  For example #13 (No castration) and #17 (Not to crossbreed animals) do not easily fit in one of the seven basic Noachide commandments.

Comment: 420 is divisible by 7, fwiw.

Comment: Which gives us about 60 per...

Comment: Not a PhD thesis, but Rabbi Lichtenstein wrote a book which you've described here. I don't think it's on the internet, but I did find a summary of it here: http://en.wikinoah.org/index.php?title=Aaron_Lichtenstein#Conclusions

Comment: Rabbi Lichtenstein's count adds up to 66, though, according to that website's summary

Comment: (Not to be confused with [Rabbi Aharon Lichtenstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharon_Lichtenstein))

Comment: I am just discovering this thread. If there are updated sources for the list of 30 and/or the Rabbi Lichtenstein article I'd like to see both. I have seen that castration is asur for non-Jews (I think it's in the kitzur SA) but have never seen an original source that there are more than 7 Noachide commandments.