# Is Jewish -Islamic system intermingling allowed in Judaism?

Tags: islam

This well known and well learned rabbi on his popular  [facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/ben613) promotes intermingling and cross mixing of Jewish and Islamic ideas and believes that Islam is a welcome reformation of  rabbinical Judaism. He has also has many articles there showing commonality between both Judaism and Islam. Hence is it allowed for rabbis and general population to practice both Islam and Judaism simultaneously like how this rabbi seems to be doing. Also even his Jewish followers consider him well learned rabbi, So the question is does Judaism permit practicing all Islamic activities? and can Islam be welcomed as a reformation in Judaism?

He writes on [linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/in/ben613) page:

> Before the religious courts, I propose that Muslims are derived from the God-fearers mentioned in the Torah. To do this, I argue historically, that the people referred to as Muslims (before the Qur'an came) are identical with the God-fearers mentioned in the Torah and related works.

further info: alsadiqin.org/en/index.php?title=Main_Page

Note: There might be other rabbis supporting Judeo-Christian intermingling like Jews for Jesus, but here the case is different as Islam is not avodah zarah and conversion to it does not demand death .

Comment: Do you have a source for claiming that the cited rabbi is "well known" and "well learned"? I'd never heard of him before he was mentioned here a few days ago. Also, "these activities" is to vague to be answerable.

Comment: he has written various scholarly treatises : http://alsadiqin.org/en/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: @IsaacMoses he has huge following of Jews on fb page and see his about page: https://www.facebook.com/ben613/about

Comment: he is director of Jerusalem Rabbinical Court

Comment: 1) Anyone can write long treatises. 2) Your link does not contain any treatises.

Comment: @narnia, I have written [266 "scholarly treatises"](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2/isaac-moses?tab=answers) to date, but anyone who considers me "well known" or "well learned" is mistaken. Please [edit] your post to back up your claims substantively, not just with links and allusions.

Comment: If you are asking if a Jew can observe parts of Islam, then we'd have to know more about what "observing parts of Islam" means to you in specific details.

Comment: @narnia all those links show is that he's a guy with a facebook page who likes Jewish music and has a long beard. I see no evidence of notoriety, credentials, scholarliness, or that he runs a rabbinical court.

Comment: This rabbi's comments were about equating the word "Islam" with a presentation of Noachide observance. http://messiahtruth.yuku.com/topic/4308/is-this-guy-really-an-orthodox-rabbi#.VGDkkzTF_DM

Comment: most of his interesting research is here http://www.facebook.com/ben613

Comment: @narnia there is no content there unless you are a facebook member.  Please, if there's something specific to ask about, ask it.  Otherwise, you're really just saying, "is this guy ok?" without giving any information about what he says.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman public site has his research http://alsadiqin.org/en/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: @narnia please insert relevant content into the text of the question.  If there's too much to put in a question, then it's likely an overly-broad question.

Comment: Is your question "Is Islam a valid form of Judaism?"?

Comment: Are you the same user as [this other narnia](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/7361/narnia)?

Comment: @MonicaCellio thats an interesting question to ask here , tangentially related to this question. This question asks about simultaneous practice of a Jew practicing both islamic and judaic practices

Comment: @MonicaCellio same user, I forgot password

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification.  How do you see someone being able to simultaneously practice Islam and Judaism when they have some conflicting commandments?

Comment: You can have the accounts merged so you'll have all your posts in one place.  Use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page, include the links to both profiles, and explain what happened.

Comment: I dont see any significant conflict from  the side of Judaism, like a Jew can pray Muslim salah and make jewish prayers too

Comment: @narnia That is not relevant _content_, that is a URL and doesn't add anything to your question.

Comment: from the Jewish side, as soon as anyone accepts Mohammed as a prophet, or the koran as a valid text, isn't one violating basic principles of Jewish belief?

Comment: @Danno No , IIRC Maimonides has clearly stated that even  conversion to Islam does not violate any major principles of Judaism. Muslims do NOT believe torah to be corrupt, Muhammad himself ruled with the verse of torah in one of the hadith and he never explicitly said that  torah is corrupt, his accusation was only on the rabbis(Not even all rabbis) , much like the reform judaism and Karaite judaism.

Comment: More ever in the Jewish Encyclopedia , we find the fact that , belief in Muhammad is not equatable to Idolatry and hence wont demand sacrifice of life as is the case of the law for Idolatry, thus making Islam simply as a sect within Judaism:

Rabbi M. Friedländer in ("Guide of the Perplexed," i., xvii., xxxiii., et seq.), in which Islam is declared to be simply a belief in Mohammed, and that Islam is not idolatry, to avoid which only the Law demands the sacrifice of life.(Jewish Encyclopedia)

Comment: Rambam wrote in the iggeret Hashmad about (verbal only) forced conversions to Islam, whether they should be avoided via martyrdom or necessitated conversion back to Judaism after the pressure had been removed, not about willing conversions or acting/living as a Muslim with Muslim beliefs in concert with Judaism. Saying that making a verbal declaration is not demanding of self-sacrifice under the terms of A"Z is not the same as condoning practicing that religion -- if so, the Rambam wouldn't have exhorted people either to flee Spain or live indoors avoiding any attention.

Comment: what about davening with the Muslim prayers?

Comment: @narnia Davening with Muslim prayers would not fulfill a Jewish person's obligation to pray. We have a formulaic prayer which cannot be substituted with something else.

Comment: but what about person who thinks it can be substituted?

Comment: nope, no such claim was made by an actual torah jew. The rambam only wrote that in a life and death situation, its better to convert to islam than to be excecuted, but that doesnt mean anything

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There has certainly been some cross-pollination of ideas over the years, e.g. certain moral lessons that you'd see in the classical Jewish philosophical work *Hovot HaLevavot* also appear in the Hadith. And as Islam is clearly a monotheistic faith, it avoids the problems posed by laws about "idols" or "pagans." (E.g. *halacha* has a lot of problems with a Jew entering a pagan temple, but not a mosque.) Maimonides wrote (just before the year 1200) that Islam spread the language of prophetic monotheism to many peoples that Judaism didn't reach. He also wished that Jews would show the same decorum in their synagogues that Muslims do in their mosques.

However, good fences make good neighbors, too. Islam and Judaism are two different faiths, and we honor neither of them by confusing that line. Judaism did not and can not accept that its tradition of laws were -- abrogated, deprecated, reinterpreted, whatever you want to call it -- by Mohammad. Jews are allowed to drink alcohol. (Now you'll find Jewish cultures that drink more, and some that drink less, and many Jews may even find the Islamic practice of abstinence to be laudable, but Judaism never did and never will ban alcohol entirely.) Muslims are monotheists but not Jews, and thus Jews are not allowed to marry them. And if a Jewish man married a Muslim woman, *neither* faith would consider the child to be legally one of their own. (*Halacha* defines Jewish status as matrilineal; *sharia* defines Islamic status as patrilineal.)

I've never heard of the rabbi you're quoting, and I really don't care. It's the same now as it was when Maimonides wrote extensively about this 800 years ago. They are two different faiths.

Comment: reform Judaism too does not uphold the traditional rabbinical law as written in the tag here itself

Comment: @narnia it starts with traditional rabbinic law as a "vote", then works from there based on understandings of personal autonomy and morality.

Comment: I don't see what Reform Judaism has to do with this.  Narnia, you also tagged the question with that and I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Judaism is not for [reformation](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0017_0_16560.html)

it is for jews to do the will of G-D almighty

we have enough to do without any changes

Judaism supports Islam's trying to keep the Seven Laws of Noah (keep it up)

1. The singularity of God. (That is, to believe in God.)
2. No
   idolatry.
3. No blasphemy.
4. To pray.
5. No false oaths.
6. No
   suicide.
7. No murder.
8. No adultery.
9. Formal marriages via
   bride price and marriage gifts.
10. No incest with a sister.
11. No homosexuality.
12. No bestiality.
13. No castration.
14. Not
    to eat an animal that died naturally.
15. Not to eat a limb of a
    living creature.
16. Not to eat or drink blood.
17. Not to
    crossbreed animals.
18. [justice.]
19. To offer ritual sacrifices.
20. No theft.
21. To respect father and mother.
22. No Molech
    worship (Deuteronomy 18:10).
23. No witchcraft.
24. No
    soothsayers.
25. No conjurers.
26. No sorcerers.
27. No ghost
    meeting.
28. No consulting devil-spirits.
29. No wizardry.
30. No
    consulting the dead.

from [What are the 30 Mitzvot for Bnei Noach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16239/what-are-the-30-mitzvot-for-bnei-noach)