# Do Jews need to care about non-Jewish homosexuality?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, sexuality

Since there is currently no way and/or need for Jews to administer capital punishment to gentiles who violate the 7 Noahide laws, is there any halachic reason for a Jew to care whether or not a non-Jew engages in homosexuality?

I am asking if there is any halachic basis to mandate that a Jew care (if you prefer 'actively object') about non-Jewish homosexuality today. If no such mandate exists, that does not necessarily mean the inverse is true (i.e. that you may actively accommodate this behavior).

To be clear, this is **not** related to chinuch or the desire not to be exposed and influenced by practices that are antithetical to the Torah. I am asking this in a purely halachic context.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8477/what-is-the-halachic-source-for-objection-to-gay-civil-marriage

Comment: To the same extent that we care if a non-Jew eats meat from a living animal, right?

Comment: רבי הונא בשם רבי אמר: דור המבול לא נימוחו מן העולם עד שכתבו גמומסיות לזכר ולבהמה

Comment: @sam would that apply today? would our generation be comparable to that generation in any other way? Could it be that Chazal are not saying that was the thing that did it, but that it was the last straw?

Comment: @MonicaCellio which is to say not a whit?

Comment: It seems like such abominations can lead to the destruction of the world which is what Rav Huna is saying. It does seem like it was the last straw,but the destruction came because of it which says a lot.

Comment: @prophecy Do you want to know whether or not there is a halacha to "care", or whether it is *muttar* to support/not object to the practice?

Comment: @Fred I would collapse the two and say that actively objecting = caring. Not objecting = not caring.

Comment: @prophecy So your question concedes that one may not support or accommodate this behavior.

Comment: @Fred I am asking if there is any halachic basis to mandate that a Jew care (if you prefer 'actively object') about non-Jewish homosexuality today. If no such mandate exists that does not necessarily mean the inverse is true (ie it doesn't mean you must actively accommodate this behavior)

Comment: @prophecy Did you mean to write "may" rather than "must" at the end of that last comment?

Comment: @Fred sure 1234

Comment: Your question can be as easily asked about Jews: Since there is currently no way and/or need for *Jews* to administer capital punishment to Jews who violate Torah law, is there any halachic reason for a Jew to care whether or not a *Jew* engages in homosexuality?

Comment: Some additional comments on the question: While it is certainly true that there is no way (either practically or halachically) for us to enforce capital punishment (on anyone Jew or Gentile), it is not as clear that there is no "need" to do so. If you are going to use that phrase, you need to clarify what you mean. (I suspect you mean that we are not halachically required to even try to carry out the death penalty.)

Comment: Similarly, you need to clarify what you mean by "care" - I mean, obviously, we ought to care (i.e. feel some emotional concern) to some degree about the fact that people, including non-Jews, are not obeying God's laws. I assume that by care you mean something more than that.

Comment: @prophecy, please [edit] your answer in accordance with clarification[s] made in the comments.

Comment: Homosexuality is one of the things prohibited to non-Jews. Source: Ohr HaChaim (Bereishis 34:31 d"h vayomru hachzonah chu').

Comment: It would seem we Should care based on the fact that it effects the moral fabric of society and hence it effects the Jews to meaning if everyone is doing it so will the jew

Comment: @LazerA re "question can be as easily asked about Jews:... any halachic reason for a Jew to care whether or not a Jew engages in homosexuality?": Yes, _arvus_: that is, the principle that all Jews are (on some level) responsible for one another's breach of God's contract.

Comment: @simchastorah He explicitly excluded the concern about its influencing Jews to sin.

Comment: Chullin 98a Rashi says that "they do not write a kessubah" It seems to imply unless others can shed some light that while the non Jews never really accepted this forbidden relationship, they most certainly do not write a kessubah for one.

Comment: This question is contradictory between its title and the specifications in the first paragraph. The title relates to issues about hashkafa (belief) while the 1st paragraph limits the discussion to only halacha. For many, those 2 domains are mostly separate and discrete. But the general idea is that both Jews & non-Jews, while different, are all “possessions” of the Creator and obliged to the Owner of all. In that sense, we are all concerned that each of us fulfill the desire & will of the source of all life.

Comment: Given that we have to share the world with non-Jews, clearly yes we should care. Given that non-Jews are Hashem's children and our brothers, clearly yes we should care.

Answer (score 16):

Rambam writes in [Hilchos Melachim 8](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188353/jewish/Chapter-8.htm):10 that Moshe Rabeinu commanded us to force all humans to follow the 7 Mitzvos (and if they refuse, we must execute them).

It is quite clear that in our times we don't have the power to enforce the penalty, but that doesn't mean that we are less obligated in trying to convince all people to follow the 7 Mitzvos voluntarily.

Some would argue that this obligates Jews to actively promote observance of the 7 laws among gentiles. Others would argue that although this is theoretically true, as a matter of priorities we should expend such energies on Jewish outreach first. But I can't imagine a justification for "not caring". It is quite clear that G-d cares so obviously we should care.

Comment: @AaronShaffier - Your quotation of the Rambam is out of context. Notice that it is found in *Hil. Melakhim Umilhhamoth*. This means (and the direct surrounding context dictates) that we are not to "force" all humans to follow the *Sheva` Misswoth Benei Noahh*. Instead, **any** non-Jewish person who desires to dwell among the Jewish people in their Land as *ger toshav* needs to be compelled to strictly follow the *misswoth* that apply to him under penalty of death at the hands of the Jewish court where he dwells.

Comment: @AaronShaffier - You do not EVER see ANY of the *Hakhmei Bavel* - or even the *hakhamim* of *Eress Yisra'el* - forcing all non-Jews around them to follow the *Sheva` Misswoth.* This is because the non-Jews around them were not dwelling in the land under Jewish jurisprudence with the permission of Jewish courts as *gerei toshav*. These types of generalizations make Judaism look like a "convert or die" religion of the sword, which it is certainly not. All that the *halakhah* requires is that those who want to live in EY without converting submit themselves strictly to the universal laws. Kol tuv

Comment: Does homosexuality breach one of the 7 Mitzvot Bene Noach?

Comment: @El Shteiger According to Torah law, male-male anal sex is a capital sin, regardless if the people involved were Jewish or non-Jewish.

Answer (score 3):

This question is contradictory between its title and the specifications in the first paragraph.

The title relates to issues about hashkafa (Jewish belief and *world view*) while the first paragraph, in particular, limits the discussion to only halacha.

For many, those two domains are mostly separate and discrete.

There are ways and examples to explain this strictly in terms of halacha, like for example with the mitzvah of *tzitzit* and the mitzvot of *tefillin.* But for most, it would lose *the meaning of the belief* because they don’t properly comprehend and/or have a relationship with the mitzvot.

But the general idea is that both Jews and non-Jews, while different, are all “possessions” of the Creator and obliged to the *Owner of all* (קונה הכל).

In that sense, we are all concerned that each of us fulfill the ***desire & will*** of the source of all life (חי אני נאום יהוה). Engaging in homosexual practices and activities does not result in new life and, in fact, is equated in traditional Jewish teaching with idol worship and murder.

Rather, we are all enjoined, both Jews and non-Jews to serve G-d together. And this is like we learn from what Adam HaRishon said to all of G-d’s creations on the very first *erev Shabbat* on the sixth day of creation, like is found in [Tehillim chapter 95](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.95?lang=bi), which is said by many every Erev Shabbat.

> Come, *let **us** sing* joyously to the L-rd,
> raise a shout for ***our*** rock and deliverer;
> *let **us** come into His presence* with praise;
> *let **us** raise a shout for Him* in song!  For the L-rd is a great G-d, *the Great King of **all divine beings***.

Comment: Halacha informs hashkafa. To say otherwise makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Dude I totally agree, but many don’t view it that way. See for example the introduction of the author to Chovot HaLevavot.