# What is the halachic point of view on homosexual intercourses between Gentiles males different from anal coitus?

Tags: halacha, noachide-laws, homosexuality

I am an Italian son of Noah.

The prohibition of the homosexual intercourses   between Gentiles males is an integral part of the Noachide Precepts (see Mishneh Torah-Melacim uMilchamot 9: 5; it does not seem that lesbian relations are explicitly forbidden to  Gentiles women ).

Now, in the Babylonian Talmud there is a passage in which the male homosexual intercourse would seem to be related to the specific practice of anal coitus:

*Sanhedrin 54a*

*GEMARA: From where do we derive the prohibition and punishment for homosexual intercourse with a male? It is as the Sages taught in a baraita with regard to the verse: “And if a man lies with a male as with a woman, both of them have committed an abomination; they shall be put to death, their blood shall be upon them” (Leviticus 20:13): (….) the phrase “as with a woman [mishkevei isha],” referring to lying with a woman, appears in the plural. The verse teaches you that there are two manners of lying with a woman for which one who engages in intercourse with a woman forbidden to him is punished, vaginal and anal intercourse.*

I therefore wonder if the halachic sources allow Gentiles males  to perform homosexual acts that are different from anal coitus, such as oral sex, mutual masturbation and intercrural coitus, also because Gentiles men are not bound by the obligation of procreation and the prohibition of spread the seed in vain.

I specify that my question has no personal interest, but is exclusively set up for study purposes pertaining to the precise provisions of the Noachide Law.

Comment: Shouldn't any sexual act between two men that is not anal techinally considered a halachicaly homosexual act? The Torah only explicitly forbade anal sex. Why isn't just included in the general rubric of wasting seed which is prohibited anyways.

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv the OP is assuming that there is no prohibition on wasting seed for non-Jews.  I have no idea if that is correct or not, but that is the assumption stated:  "also because Gentiles men are not bound by the obligation of procreation and the prohibition of spread the seed in vain."

Comment: While lesbianisn is not necessarily explicitly mentioned in Scripture, I believe that the Medrash interprets that the scriptural reference to abominations of Egypt included, amongst other things, lesbian acts, seemingly implying that these are biblically forbidden to both Jew and Gentile.  Considering that there is no halachic "coitus" between women possible, this would seem to imply that other, less intimate sexual acts are also potentially forbidden to all at a biblical level.  Likewise, I believe there is a discussion regarding the permissibility/impermissibility of corollaries...

Comment: ... (אביזרייהו) of the 7 Noachide Laws, including with regard to forbidden sexual acts.

Answer (score 1):

This requires a much fuller discussion that I cannot provide at all, but I will provide some sources that seem to contribute to the discussion/learning:

The Gemara in Yevamos 55b seems to imply that other sexual actions are in general not considered "Mishkevei Isha", but rather "Peritzusa Bealma".  See first 2 sources [here](https://library.yctorah.org/2017/08/degrees-of-sexual-touch/) for full translation and explanation:

> אמר רבא: פרט לשקינא לה דרך אברים. א”ל אביי: פריצותא אסר רחמנא?
>
> רש"י - 
>   דרך אברים – מיעוך דדים ודש מבחוץ בשאר אברים. פריצותא קאסר רחמנא – בתמיה כלומר פשיטא דלאו קינוי הוא דמשום פריצותא לא מיתסרא עליה.

See also:
[https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/איסור_משכב_זכר](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%91_%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%A8)
[https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/הומוסקסואליות_בהלכה](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94)

The 2 Wikipedia pages provide other sources to this discussion (even relating to non-Jews) that I'm not sure should be copied out and written about here, for various "meta" reasons.  Other users or moderators who know the rules better than me should feel free to edit in whatever useful pieces of information found there that apply to our question and are within the appropriate boundaries of this site.