# Is it correct to say that, according to Rabbi Moshe Feinstein, lesbian relations beetween Gentiles women are not forbidden?

Tags: halacha, noachide-laws, moshe-feinstein

I'm an Italian noahide.

Through the link

http://www.hakirah.org/Vol13Rapoport.pdf

I read the article "Judaism and Homosexuality:
An Alternate Rabbinic View ", written by the English Orthodox rabbi Chaim Rapoport. On the third page of the text Rabbi Rapoport states that, according to the authoritative Posek Rabbi Moshe Feinstein, lesbian relations are not forbidden to Gentiles women. Rabbi Rapoport cites as source the text "Dibberot Moshe on Shabbat vol. 2 (New York, 1971), ch. 59, section 34 ". I have tried to find this work, without success, nor have I been able to find any further evidence regarding this halachic position of Rabbi Feinstein.
I contacted Rabbi Rapoport asking him the courtesy to give me further information on the matter, but he did not reply.

Can you help me know the aforementioned source "Dibberot Moshe on Shabbat vol. 2 (New York, 1971), ch. 59, section 34", and more generally to understand if is correct Rabbi Rapoport's statement about the position taken on the subject by  Rabbi Feinstein correct?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant text appears in [this 1996 edition of Diberot Moshe on Shabbat vol. 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47566&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=) in [chapter 53, section 35](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47566&st=&pgnum=396) and does indeed seem to say what R. Rapoport claims that it does:

> דאשה נושאת אשה דזה ודאי אינו דבר איסור לבני נח
>
> For a woman to "marry" another woman is certainly not a forbidden matter for Noahides.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Joel K Looking at what Reb Moshe is discussing there, he is distinguishing between the prohibitions related to uncovering ervah (which is related to forbidden types of sexual intercourse) and prohibitions related to someone with excessive sexual desires. Reb Moshe notes (if I see it correctly) lesbian relations between B'nai Noach relate to the latter category. Reb Moshe only notes that it is possible to understand from the wording that it might be permissible. But is certainly not recommended or encouraged. Remember Diberot Moshe is only chiddushim and not p'sak halacha.

Comment: Reb Moshe also notes there that some say the practice is forbidden (some say m'doraita, and some m'd'Rabbanan) and he tries to unravel why they have these differing views and what the practical implications are from them. But I don't see over the page that he says it is fully permitted and acceptable practice. On the contrary, he says the opposite.

Comment: @YaacovDeane As far as I can tell the thrust of R Moshe’s discussion is regarding the nature of the prohibition for Jews. I don’t see where you see in his words that it is a unacceptable for non-Jews.

Comment: @JoelK Reb Moshe is addressing how it relates to Jews primarily. But he starts to explore the subject of the prohibition as it relates to excessive sexual desire (which further on he also relates to Bnai Noach). In that context, he notes that some, like Rambam, say this type of prohibition is m'doraita. However, Reb Moshe notes that this whole subject requires (by him) further review! Keep in mind that Bnai Noach are trying to be counted as the righteous (saintly) gentiles. Indulgence of excessive desire is not among those character traits. The saintly follow equanimity (השתוות).