# Is there anything wrong with using someone's "preferred pronouns"?

Tags: halacha, gender-identity

There are many people who identify as transgender or non-binary and request that they are treated as such by other people, which includes referencing them by the pronoun that [they preferred to be called by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferred_gender_pronoun).

This may include:

- Someone who has undergone gender reassignment surgery
- Someone who now identifies themselves as the opposite gender they were assigned at birth even though they have not undergone any gender reassignment surgery.
- Someone who identifies as non-binary and prefers to be referenced by an alternative pronoun like "Ze","Ve", "Xe" etc, or exclusively using the ambiguous "They".

The question is: are there any halachic problems that would prevent an observant Jew from using someone else's preferred pronouns?

Possible factors could be:

- מדבר שקר תרחק
- מסייע לדבר עבירה
- מחזיקי ידי עוברי עבירה
- דרכי שלום

Although it is not clear if any of these would really apply in this case.

Also to consider: Would it make a difference if the person underwent gender reassignment surgery? (not sure how one would know this) Does it make a difference if the person is Jewish or non-Jewish?

Comment: 1 & 4 can be contingent on one another; IOW in keeping with 4 one may sometimes violate 1 ([related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71136/15571)); OTOH 1 might not be an issue to begin with if society recognizes/accepts a certain dialect and mode of speech (#Orwellian) in accordance with social determinations. Also no violation of 2 & 3 since such a prohibited transition is/would be done regardless how you refer to them (“[תרי עברי דנהרא](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.6b.2?with=all&lang=bi)”).

Comment: I think it terms of personal conversation, one should respect the other one's feelings and not cause embarrassment or insult. What seems more questionable is how to refer to them in areas such as tefillah where male and female tefillot are separated such as the prayer for the sick.

Comment: 1. There's a huge difference if talking in private or in public! 2. The main reason, as I remember, is the prohibition of accidental closeness as a result of confusion.

Comment: We have two "transgender" options from the Gemmorah - androgynous (both attributes) and TumTum (none). Your question can be simply rephrased of how do we address them.

Comment: @AlBerko That is an interesting question, but not the one asked here. Knowing how to address a Tumtum and Androgynous, would have little relevance in dealing with addressing a transgender person, given that many of them do not fit into either of those two categories biologically.

Comment: @Silver It's a good place to start, because the Sages should have dealt with this situation.

Comment: This is not the right place to ask such an important question - ask a rov.

Comment: I think the biggest issue here is אין מחזיקין ידי עוברי עבירה. If someone did, or is doing, something prohibited by the Torah, it's wrong to congratulate them on it, or even to give the impression that it's acceptable. Using false pronouns IMHO gives the impression that you're ok with a man becoming a woman. It's a very difficult question, because nowadays you can also get fired for "misgendering" someone. So even if it is wrong to use fake pronouns, the next question is, is this a hill you have to die on (i.e. give up your parnassa on principle)?

Comment: @AlBerko the tumtum and androginus cases are not comparable. Those are cases where the person was *born* that way; they have no choice in the matter. And there are clear halachos for how to handle the safek. Our case here is a natural-born man/woman who has voluntarily decided to switch genders, which (a) is assur, and (b) has no halachic effect on their actual gender.

Comment: @KovyJacob you make a fair point, but this is not just a personal shaalah of how to handle an individual situation. We're dealing with a categorical issue, and honestly, we need a generational psak for how to deal with these situations, because it's becoming more and more common, and sticking our heads in the sand is not going to work.

Comment: @ShaulBehr in fact, it is even not allowed to congratulate a Jew on their wedding to a non-Jew, for example. Or compliment someone's not-tzniut clothing, etc. And *especially* since society is pushing heavily that using someone's preferred pronouns indicates that you approve of their identity/actions, I can see it being problematic. As someone else mentioned, another question is if you would be allowed to do so in cases where you risk losing your job, etc.

Comment: The chances are such people are either shoteh l'davar echad, or tinok shenishba, and in both cases halacha provides ample rooms to be highly sensitive to them. See AH OC 156:11 for eg. So ein machzikin and the like are questionable. The other issues remain. Most likely the issue will boil down to simply is it allowed to use the pronouns in general, and then the special case of a situation of ideological challenge to Yiddishkeit/Emet

Comment: @AlBerko it's already been pointed out but I just want to state it in different words: Intersex is not the same as transgender, for the reasons given.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Contrary to Al’s claim, the Torah also addresses people whose soul is rooted in one gender and born into a physical body of the opposite gender. If I recall correctly, this is discussed by Ramban in connection with Abraham, Yitzchok & Rivkah. I believe it is also discussed by Yechiel Michel, the Maggid of Zlotchov in Mayim Rabbim or one of his other seforim.

Answer (score 9):

While this seems to be a highly sensitive topic, and the opinion of one Rav is not universally binding to say the least, the answer to the question is yes, there is a halachic issue. [Here](https://anash.org/how-should-i-deal-with-preferred-pronouns/) is a Rav, Dayan Levi Yitzchok Raskin, Rov of Anash in London, who deals with this exact question. He concludes that it is an issue of lo silbash based on the fact that Rashi explains the prohibition to mean dressing like a woman in order to mingle with women. He concludes that this is the epitome of doing something like a woman to be able to mingle with women and is a direct violation of this biblical commandments. Once that’s established, calling them by their preferred pronouns would indicate your agreement and approval of their violation and would be prohibited as a machzik yedei ovrei aveira.

Comment: Does this apply if the person in question is not Jewish?

Comment: It wouldn’t seem so. If you listen to the podcast, he discusses it from another angle but not halachic. Interestingly, he says that in USA a person who wants to undergo this type of procedure needs to have someone vouch for them to say they are of sound mind. Many times people ask their employer to sign for them. If a non Jewish employee asks his Jewish employer to sign for him, he says is an extremely tough question that he can’t answer.

Comment: Interesting. I'll put it on my listening list.

Comment: This also wouldn't apply if the person chose a non binary gender. Lo silbash doesn't apply when the clothes are worn by both genders. (I still haven't listen yet)

Comment: @user6591 it certainly seems like an avenue to explore though. If 'switching gender' is prohibited, it _might_ be derived that denying one's own gender (or even denying the concept of gender) is in some way prohibited too.

Answer (score 4):

To recap your question:

1. **Are there any halachic problems that would prevent an observant Jew from using someone else's** (*meaning someone who either identifies as transgender or non-binary, or who has undergone gender reassignment surgery, whether Jewish or non-Jewish*) **preferred pronouns?**

The simple answer is yes, for an observant Jew this type of practice, meaning acceding to their request and using their preferred, personal pronouns, ***like they do themselves***, is prohibited according to halacha.

The prohibition comes from the written Torah, Vayikra 20:23 which says:

> וְלֹ֤א תֵֽלְכוּ֙ בְּחֻקֹּ֣ת הַגּ֔וֹי אֲשֶׁר־אֲנִ֥י מְשַׁלֵּ֖חַ מִפְּנֵיכֶ֑ם כִּ֤י אֶת־כׇּל־אֵ֙לֶּה֙ עָשׂ֔וּ וָאָקֻ֖ץ בָּֽם׃
>
> ***You shall not follow the practices* of the nation** that I am driving out before you. For it is because they did all these things that I abhorred them

And also from Vayikra 18:3 and 18:26 which say:

> כְּמַעֲשֵׂ֧ה אֶֽרֶץ־מִצְרַ֛יִם אֲשֶׁ֥ר יְשַׁבְתֶּם־בָּ֖הּ לֹ֣א תַעֲשׂ֑וּ וּכְמַעֲשֵׂ֣ה אֶֽרֶץ־כְּנַ֡עַן אֲשֶׁ֣ר אֲנִי֩ מֵבִ֨יא אֶתְכֶ֥ם שָׁ֙מָּה֙ לֹ֣א תַעֲשׂ֔וּ וּבְחֻקֹּתֵיהֶ֖ם לֹ֥א תֵלֵֽכוּ׃
>
> ***You shall not copy the practices* of the land of Egypt** where you dwelt, **nor of the land of Canaan** to which I am taking you; nor shall you follow their laws.
>
> וּשְׁמַרְתֶּ֣ם אַתֶּ֗ם אֶת־חֻקֹּתַי֙ וְאֶת־מִשְׁפָּטַ֔י וְלֹ֣א תַעֲשׂ֔וּ מִכֹּ֥ל הַתּוֹעֵבֹ֖ת הָאֵ֑לֶּה הָֽאֶזְרָ֔ח וְהַגֵּ֖ר הַגָּ֥ר בְּתוֹכְכֶֽם׃
>
> But **you must keep My laws and My rules, and you must not do *any of those abhorrent things***, neither the citizen nor the stranger who resides among you;

To understand how this seemingly innocent and unrelated action, to follow the request of the transgender and/or non-binary community, to describe them by their preferred personal pronouns (***like the practice which they do themselves***) can be connected to these clear prohibitions in the written Torah requires reviewing how these concepts are taught via our Oral law across many different sources.

The first source to review is [Sifra (Torat Kohanim, Vienna edition, Acharei Mot, Chapter 13](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40719&st=&pgnum=181))

The beginning of this chapter emphasizes that **both Jews and non-Jews are warned *by the Creator of us all* regarding prohibited sexual practices**. Specific details and consequences may vary depending upon status, but this subject is addressed to everyone.

These prohibitions also apply to both men and to women.

It is no surprise that our generation faces this specific challenge now, at the end of exile and the beginning of the final redemption. It is found in the commentary of the Rogatchover Gaon to the Chumash, parshat Acharei Mot, 18:2 quoting Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi from the Sifra 13:4 which says that G-d knew that in the end Israel would be broken, disrupted and disconnected through *prohibited sexual relationships*. (לינתק בעריות) That their exposure to this type of sin (*during their enslavement* *and exile*) would damage and corrupt them (*much like severe Post Traumatic Stress Disorder*). And the Rogatchover points explicitly to [Sanhedrin 63b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.63b.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and the quote of Rav Yehuda in the name of Rav who says:

> Rav Yehuda says that Rav says: **The Jewish people** knew that idol worship is of no substance; they did not actually believe in it. And they **worshipped idols only in order to permit themselves to engage in forbidden sexual relations in public**, ***since most rituals of idol worship would include public displays of forbidden sexual intercourse***.

That (*exposure to*) sin causes sin. [And this was actually the advice that Bilaam gave to Balak](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Numbers.25.1.1?lang=bi&with=all) after failing to curse the Jewish people during the first redemption. His curses being converted into prophecies about the future, final redemption.

[image: Rogatchover Commentary]

In Sifra 13:6-7 it distinguishes the practices specifically of the Egyptians and the Canaanites of that time because they were the most extreme examples of their time in regard to sexually deviant practices. It points out that these types of practices are considered a spiritual pollution of the individual and that this spiritual pollution of the individual also results in the pollution of surrounding physical environment to such an extent that the surrounding environment (*literally the land*) will no longer support them and will eventually vomit them out! (Vayikra 18:25, 18:28 and 20:22)

If today you look around with alarm at the [widespread and varied destruction of the environment on a global scale](https://m.jpost.com/environment-and-climate-change/article-744003) and the [impending signs of a potential mass extinction event](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/brv.12974), the [enormous forest fires caused by *acts of G-d* making the very air of millions of people unfit to breath](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/hundreds-fires-control-canada-worst-185017836.html), and the [multiple volcanoes](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-12113795/Huge-swathes-Mexico-blanketed-dust-Popocatepetl-volcano-continues-spew-ash.html) spewing [ash, smoke, lava and sulfur fumes](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-12170245/Kilauea-volcano-Hawaiis-Big-Island-erupts-wild-explosion-magma-lava.html) (*[literally fire and brimstone](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-12110111/Millions-told-ready-evacuate-amid-volcanic-activity-Mexico.html)*), it is worth reflecting upon [what the Torah teaches is its spiritual cause](https://www.israelnationalnews.com/news/372494).

It is very much in keeping with the concept of Divine Judgement *Middah-Keneged-Middah* (Measure for Measure) but in an inverse relationship to ***the Source of all life***, meaning G-d. Like is emphasized within the Torah in regard to the concept of the first commandment: **to be fruitful and multiply**, meaning the perpetuation of the species, **diversification and increase of life is a primary sign of a healthy and thriving environment**. (See [Bereshit 1:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.22?lang=bi&aliyot=0) and [Bereshit 1:28](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.28?lang=bi&aliyot=0))

The political justification of the LGBTQ+ movement is all about *diversity*, but in alignment with *the opposite of life*.

This is the underlying message from the Torah about the causes behind the mass extinction event recounted in connection with Noach and the flood. See [Bereshit 6:1-13 and the commentaries](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.6.1-13?lang=bi&aliyot=0) there for details.

Although we have a Heavenly promise that a mass extinction event via water will not be repeated, we do not have a guarantee that we will not experience another mass extinction event by other means, be it by disease or some other catastrophe like earthquake, volcano, extreme climate change or devastating pollution of the environment.

Sifra goes on to explain that *Idol Worship*, *Prohibited Sexual Practices* and *Murder* are all **from the same spiritual root**. In Sifra 13:9 it also connects this to the concept of *passing sons and daughters through the flames of Molach.* (Devarim 18:10)

Essentially this is the wasting of ones reproductive potential, which is comprised of both sons and daughters, by indulging irrationally in obsessive excess with the *flames* of natural sexual desire (this desire is something G-d created for a blessing and for good in connection to the reproduction and preservation of the species, meaning the commandment to *Be fruitful and multiply*). Like G-d told to Adam HaRishon, he was to do this commandment and to preserve and guard it! (Bereshit 2:15)

In the commentary of the Raavad to Sifra 13:9 he emphasizes that any of the customs and practices like excessive preoccupation with personal grooming and beautification associated with these prohibited sexual behaviors are included in the prohibition against following the ways of the Amorites.

And Rabbi Meir also explains that this activity is associated with the Amorites, *who are also connected with the Amalekites* and their allies in Sodom and Gomorrah. (Bereshit 14:1-7)

And this prohibition is explained in detail by [Yerucham Fishel Perla in his commentary to Saadia Gaon's Sefer HaMitzvot, Negative Commandments, Number 12](https://www.sefaria.org/Commentary_on_Sefer_Hamitzvot_of_Rasag%2C_Negative_Commandments.12.3?vhe=Sefer_Hamitzvot_L%27Rasag,_Warsaw,_1914_--_vol._2&lang=bi) and how it includes also their customs and practices. It is not limited to actual worship of a physical idol, but includes their mode of dress, hairstyles and grooming and even unusual behavior. All these types of things vary according to what is practiced in that region and generation.

It is also the view of Rambam as found in his [Sefer HaMitvot, Negative Mitzvot 30](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaMitzvot%2C_Negative_Commandments.30.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), and [Mishneh Torah, Sefer HaMada, Hilchot Avodah Zarah, 10:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.10.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and for deeper understanding of Rambam's position see [Moreh Nevuchim, Section 3:37](https://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Part_3.37.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

This is also the view found in Sefer Yere'im by the Tosaphist, Rabbi Eliezer of Metz, see Sefer Yere'im with commentary To'afot Romm, Freidman Edition, Vol.3, Amud 7, [Siman 271](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Yereim.271.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [Siman 313](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Yereim.313.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) who explains that this prohibition  pertains to practices that lead to and are in support of men marrying men, women marrying women, women marrying more than one man, and men marrying a woman and her daughter, etc.

> ובחוקותיהם לא תלכו **לא אמרתי אלא בחוקים החקוקים להם ולאבותיהם מה היו עושים איש נושא איש ואשה נושא אשה אשה נשאת לשנים ואיש נושא אשה ובתה** לכך נאמר ובחוקותיהם לא תלכו:

The same view is expressed in the Semag, [Sefer Mitzvot Gadolot of Rabbi Moshe of Coucy, Negative Commandments, 50](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Mitzvot_Gadol%2C_Negative_Commandments.50.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

It is also the position found in [Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh Deah, Siman 178](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.178.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) which says:

> One [i.e., a Jew] **should not follow the customs of non-Jews** (nor should one try to resemble them)

To which the Rema, Rabbi Moshe Isserles emphasizes:

> **Rather, one [i.e., a Jew] should be distinct from them** [i.e., non-Jews] in one’s manner of dress and **in all of one’s actions. But all of this [i.e., these restrictions] *apply only to things that non-Jews do for the sake of licentiousness*.**

And a thorough treatment can also be found in the Responsa of the third Lubavitcher Rebbe in [Tzemach Tzedek, Section Yoreh Deah, Siman 91](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1614&st=&pgnum=161).

Comment: How do you know this practice is included in this prohibition? Restating lots of sources for a commonly known prohibition is not supporting the central claim of your answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA Read the 3rd section of the link provided to Saadia Gaon. This concept comes up in many areas in Shulchan Aruch also. In this day and age, and in particular in the way it is presented publicly and politically, like is also asked in this question by the OP, it falls into this category. If you have an alternative viewpoint, feel free to post an answer. This question has sat for 4 years without a response from anyone including you.

Comment: My viewpoint is don't make things up even if you don't know the answer. If there's a relevant part of the citation, quote that instead of the stuff you did quote.

Comment: @YaacovDeane consider providing only the relevant information as well as your conclusions based thereon. Long megillas will burn us all out.

Comment: @HershyS. I appreciate your comment and that was my initial, short answer. But the moderator who commented first made the suggestion that I was "making things up" because I only furnished a link to Saadia Gaon's commentary saying to see his explanation, after indicating the practice is prohibited. There is no question the practice is prohibited by Gaonim, Rishonim, Acharonim and latest Poskim Gadolim based on the Torah sources I cite. It is a wonder to me that this answer has received 6 down votes.

Comment: Regarding the ways of the nations, interestingly Rama says in SA YD 178 "וכן שעושין משום כבוד או טעם אחר מותר", could be used against you! :)

Comment: @RabbiKaii The comment from the Rema is about activities that are not associated with “licentiousness”. You should take a look in your Webster’s Dictionary at the meaning of that word. And then look at what the Siman in Yoreh Deah is talking about. Then put it in the context of this question. The plain meaning is absolutely clear. I cannot recommend strongly enough actually reading the links I have posted to this. It will be a very sobering eye-opener. תורת אמת. Read the response from the Tzemach Tzedek. I’ve looked at dozens of Poskim on this. The answer is accurate, true and correct.

Comment: @YaacovDeane thank you for taking the time to try to give this question an honest and halachic answer. I fear that views on this issue have become so contraverted and  polarized (which of course in itself is binary!) that reactions to this answer may not make much sense

Comment: Also, @YaakovDeane, it may be worth remembering that it was over this issue that we lost beloved moderator Monica

Comment: @יהושעק Thank you. I remember Monica well and had many excellent communications with her. Although I do not know much about the details of her conflict, in my opinion, our site has lost a valuable contributor through her loss. That said, the very basis of this site, like is stated in the welcome tour is about asking questions and finding their answers as found in traditional Orthodox Judaism & its textual sources. I am looking now at the commentary of Rabbi Moshe Alshich to Acharei Mot 18:1-5. He emphasizes that the entire Torah hangs upon & is dependent on this specific subject.

Comment: FWIW, my downvote on this post has nothing to do with emotional or political feelings. It's because this post does not clearly address the question at hand, which is about pronouns, in conversation. Instead, it presents a large and growing mass of material on possibly-related issues without the sort of organization and argumentation that would help a reader navigate all this material and understand how it may address the question. If you're interested in fixing these issues, consider adding only material that will help the reader in these ways and subtracting any material that doesn't.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Because the actual question was stated poorly, I restated it in brief to clarify what the OP was asking. (Should an observant Jew accede to the requested conduct of the transgender/gender dismorphic/homosexual community?) I then answered in brief, which most people would not understand or comprehend, no, it is prohibited. The balance of the answer is to provide the traditional sources with some help on language translation to explain why it is prohibited according to traditional Orthodox Judaism & to give it context in current Jewish life. Please reconsider your downvote.

Comment: @IsaacMoses In case you miss the “why” of the prohibition, halacha and the Torah equate the LGBTQ? lifestyle with idol worshippers. (Not my innovation!) The prohibition of not following their conduct, general customs and behavior in any way is universal if it is associated with acceptance or condoning of their licentious practices. The personal pronoun practice that they demand & practice themselves is forbidden. It is being implemented in many schools, businesses & other institutions across the United States, often by mandate.

Comment: @IsaacMoses One final detail you probably should note is that several of seemingly unrelated details in my longer explanation are responding to the specific requests for “consideration” from the OP in the balance of their question and particularly in their closing paragraph.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I think your case is quite good now, you've brought many sources that all are pretty pashut pertaining to this practice of pronouns, and it would be hard to argue against them applying. I would be interested if the initial responses would review what you wrote and make further comments.

Comment: @RabbiKaii to my mind, the main issue with this post, which is a core issue, is that it assumes but does not demonstrate the *metziut* point that self-pronoun-choice is linked to forbidden sexual unions [in the manner that would implicate it in the cited Halachic statements]. Secondarily, my previous comment about organization remains unaddressed. The longer an answer gets, the more structure is necessary to make it readable. This post could address the question much more convincingly by focusing on one authoritative source and linking it clearly to the practice in question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I'd be up for discussing that if you like, as we both have a different point of view so I think the discussion would be valuable. If you are game, feel free to open a chat.

Comment: @RabbiKaii the only point of view I'm advocating for is that answer posts should clearly address the question at hand, and the only import of that is one vote on this post. If you think that this post clearly addresses the question at hand, you're welcome to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of sources (eg https://www.torahmusings.com/2021/11/an-apostates-son/) on the importance of not calling people by a name that they will find humiliating or embarrassing. That can easily be read as extending to not using pronouns that someone will find humiliating or embarrassing.

Comment: I'm not sure that applies to someone who is actually doing something wrong themselves...

Comment: If someone finds it humiliating to be called "Jew" should we not call them that? Or "Cohen" if they are a Cohen?

Comment: Hi Zarka. Thanks for contributing. The article you link to is discussing someone who is following the Torah. But this question is addressing people who are actively rejecting G-d's commandments and His Torah. They fall into a very special category that is outside of what Rabbi Student is dealing with. You might find the link I posted to Rambam's Moreh Nevuchim (Guide to the Perplexed) helpful in understanding this unique circumstance.

Comment: It may astonish you all to learn that I don’t consider someone nominating a preferred pronoun to be doing something wrong. I’m also not familiar with any pasuk forbidding such an action.

Comment: Moreover, the rule against using humiliating language quite explicitly extends to alluding to someone’s misdeeds (see Bava Metzia 58ff).

Comment: I'm not asking in order to question or judge your morality, I genuinely want to know what you think the limits are for acquiescing people of their desire to not be referred to by what they are. If they don't want to be called a Jew or a Cohen  were two examples to test that. If someone identifies as a shoteh or eved and you know they are not, are you supposed to deal with them as if they are and if so to what degree? What of the halachot applicable to those? All in order to avoid embarrassing them? This is an important question so please can we discuss it and not take things personally

Comment: If someone identifies as a woman, but is a man, when you call them up to Torah do you say ploni bat ploni? Are we allowed to call them up by whatever _name_ they want as many times these people change their name and would like wish to not be referred to by their Hebrew name as given at their bar mitzvah too.

Comment: If a rabbi who got a valid semicha transitions or identifies as a woman now, what do we do about their embarrassment and calling them a rabbi. Is this now a legit way to get female rabbis?

Comment: @RabbiKaii The questions you're asking are legitimate ones, as is the overall question of where to draw the line, but I'll just point out that all of the questions you're posing (except for the one about calling someone "Rabbi") are qualitatively different than from the question at hand, which is about conversation and presumably not about assignment of various kinds of Halachic status.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I am trying to keep all my examples within this answers logic of making this into a question of embarrassment and testing it's limits. I apologize if I went outside that inadvertently

Comment: As for humiliation, if someone genuinely believes that someone else is a male, but that person wants them to use a different pronouns, i.e. wants them to say something they do not believe, isn't that also humiliating? What if that person also believes they have a religious duty to uphold emes or any of the other suggestions in the OP, which would make their humiliation worse? I honestly hope you don't think I am just being pushy or facetious, or mocking your point. I wish I could convey how sincere I am being, this is a serious issue, humiliation. Whose humiliation comes first?

Comment: @RabbiKaii If I genuinely want to call you by a derogatory nickname, I’m not allowed to. Is that humiliating me? Not really, but even if it was, that’s the halachah. 
Is it untruthfulness? No more than substituting someone’s grandfather’s name for their father’s in their patronymic. 
I don’t see why pronouns are different. It seems to me that the clear theme here is ‘don’t call people what they don’t want to be called’.

Answer (score -1):

Judaism is willing in other instances to obscure certain truths for good reasons. One example being many Kethubboth list the bride to be as a virgin even if she may not truly be so. Because of this I personally see no issue using someone's preferred pronouns since I'm not going to pull down their pants and confirm, just like no one is pulling down pants doing virginity tests anymore.

I offer this advice when everyone is acting in good faith. If someone is pressuring you, or demanding you use a pronoun, that's an entirely different case. If you personally struggle with using a preferred pronoun when someone presents as the other pronoun (identifies as she but still has beard and mustache because they haven't started hormones) then I would apologize ahead of time to said a person and say you may make mistakes in using their preferred pronoun. Someone who is working with you in good faith should reflect the grace you are giving them and you should respect the grace they are giving you.

Note: This answer is personal and does not reflect any ideas beyond what is strictly written here. I'm not delving into anyone's halakhic status pre or post surgery. Like one of the other answers here, just as we avoid embarrassing people by mentioning their virginity status, or avoid using certain names, I personally avoid embarassing someone by fighting over pronouns.

Update: After further considerations I now offer another reason one could use personal pronouns. More than likely you have already used the wrong pronouns and haven't even noticed. For some transsexuals it's more obvious what their birth gender was, so I can understand someone wanting to die on the hill of stating birth gender at all time. But many people who identify as trans will start hormones and surgery, and some of them will look completely like their desired gender and nothing like their birth gender. In your life you have probably already used the "preferred pronouns" because you assumed they were the gender they introduced themselves as. Based on this doubt, I think it's completely appropriate to use preferred pronouns because due to modern medications and surgeries, you might never be able to tell the difference until you pull someone's pants down.

Comment: "I'm not going to pull down their pants and confirm" - what if it is clearly obvious, or if you have actually been to the mikva with them etc?

Comment: What if you slept with someone and therefore knew they weren't a virgin anymore. If they were getting married later would you argue with her, the spouse, and the Rav that the ketubah can't say virgin?

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with your whole point, just questioning that part of the argument

Comment: Question all you want. This is a personal opinion answer in which I'm trying to convey that one can find space to be respectful because if we are willing to say x things aren't our business, then it seems to me that y things  aren't our business either.

Comment: I understand your sentiment and am also inclined toward whatever can be done to help people in these conditions to find their way back to the path of Torah and traditional Jewish law. But in the same breath, you cannot advocate something that is false according to the Torah. Regarding your specific answer, it doesn't answer what the OP specifically asked. The OP asks specifically what is taught about this according to halacha about indulging the request to refer to the transgender or gender dismorphic person by personal pronouns opposite of their birth gender (like is their custom).

Comment: The fact that we allow lying about one thing does not imply we allow lying about anything. In that sense this answer presents a fallacious argument

Comment: @DoubleAA lying for the sake of kavod habruit which is Aaron's argument depends on the degree of indignity (Tosafot, Shevuot 30b), so I wouldn't call it fallacious, but at least _questionable_. Aaron, I'm wondering how you feel about using non-standard pronouns as this answer seems for the most part to deal with simply switching pronouns?

Comment: @RabbiKaii the argument presented is objectively fallacious since the conclusion doesn't follow from the premises. Nothing to debate about that

Comment: @YaacovDeane If it were up to me I would advocate of removing of a woman's virginity status from the ketubah altogether rather than lie about it. The fact that we as a group have decided that it's okay to lie about such matters opens a door. We can argue all day long wether it's appropriate that I'm opening the door this much, but I didn't open this door. The Torah is VERY clear about the importance of a woman's virginity in terms of marriage. I would have never thought we would establish a halakhic norm to lie about it

Comment: @YaacovDeane And if we are willing to lie about this very clear detail of the Torah. Then why not a concept that wasn't even truly a thing yet? Yes clearly there were crossdressers, and homosexuals, but transgender people who could take hormones and have surgeries? This is a whole new field of existence. And so if the Rabbis are going to lie about a woman's virginity, to which the bible mentions and is very clear on. Then who am I to care about transgenders which didn't even exist then?

Comment: @Aaron It would be worthwhile investigating when and where the precise language required in the ketubah started. You may discover that it’s not as you are assuming. I have seen many ketubot with edits made to the standard wording by the supervising Rav to adapt to the specifics of a marriage.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I modified my own ketubah to describe my wife as a virgin unto me (which was true). But you know exactly what I'm talking about. It's a very common practice. But here's where we would all agree. Just because we write virgin on the ketubah, that doesn't mean we all agree to suspend reality and believe this woman is a virgin. And if this woman demanded that we say she is a virgin who had never had sex I think we would all agree one should not do so and such a woman is overstepping their bounds. We lie for the sake of a happy marriage and happy friendships for everyone involved

Comment: @YaacovDeane All I'm advocating for is the use of pronouns. If a trans person asks you to call them a man when clearly they are a woman, that is them overstepping their bounds. If they ask you to tell other people that they are x when they are y, I would say you should not do so. You can refer to someone by their pronouns without getting into their actual gender or sex. Just like we can refer to someone as a virgin even if we don't confirm with bloody cloths anymore. But we do so for the sake of peace, not to deny reality.

Comment: @Aaron I understand. You are seeking some kind of compromise that sounds reasonable. But if you actually read the sources I link to, you will discover that this is a “no compromise” issue. It is essentially a denial of G-d’s Kingship (Kabbalat Ole Malchut Shemayim). I have to admit, as I looked deeper into this subject, even I was surprised. But it is true and accurate as I report in my answer. If you have the language skills, I strongly recommend actually reading all the sources I provide. They are all 100% traditional and authentic.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I agree with you that your sources are true and authentic. And we all have gentile modes of dress unless you were an early 1900s Baghdadi Jew who have a tradition of not dressing like the gentiles. We all eat variations of gentile foods and speak gentile languages. We literally compromise all of these things all the time. We can't even get through half our calendar without speaking gentile God names. I'm not a Rabbi and so I'm not playing gatekeeper to when we lie for this and not that. You can choose to die on this hill, and may God grant you many merits for it.

Comment: @RabbiKaii We buy into saying she is a virgin because of a social contract. We aren't checking, and she's not making a big deal about her past or her virginity status. We are opting to choose their relationship together, and our relationship with them. If someone is clearly asking to be called a reasonable pronoun in a reasonable way, is acting kindly and respectfully toward you, then buy into the social contract and don't check what's in their pants. But if the other person doesn't buy into the social contract then by all means stand your ground.