# Should Jews worry about whom non-Jewish governments recognize as "married"?

Tags: gentiles, marriage, politics-government, noachide-laws, homosexuality

It says in *Pirqei Avot*h 2:3

"*hawwu nizhirin be-reshuth*"

"Be wary of the [non-Jewish] government..."

Lately, I have read alot of commentary from religious Jews in America about the Supreme Court's decision to legalize and recognize same-sex marriages throughout the US. With all of the pressing issues in the Jewish world, it made me wonder why religious Jews - even to the point of getting involved with and interacting with government representatives - would put so much effort into a decision that ultimately doesn't have any bearing on them.

I am not asking whether or not Jews should care about the moral behavior of the non-Jewish world. And I am not asking whether or not Jews should pray out of concern for their non-Jewish government, wherever they happen to live in the Diaspora. Rather, I am wondering if religious should ***involve*** themselves with the legislation of non-Jewish governments regarding homosexuality or homosexual unions, through social action, etc.

I mean, isn't this type of legislation the business of non-Jews as their carry out - for better or for worse - the seventh *misswath Benei Noahh* (i.e. *dinim*)? Is it our place? And does such involved ultimately change the number of homosexual couples who get "married" and play house in the US anyway?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8477/5323 (duplicate?)