# Why aren't there any Gay people in the Bible?

Tags: tanach, sexuality, sin, homosexuality

Our scriptures (the Bible and later) are full of people who sinned.
Every kind of sin, including murder and sexual sins.
The sinners are both from our people as well as non-Jews.
Some of the sinners repent, others receive Godly or earthly punishment.

Nevertheless, there are no homosexuals in the Bible. Yes, sexual relationships between men are forbidden. But there are no concrete example of homosexuals in the Bible and as far as I know in later sources.

As opposed to other sinners (killers, adulterers, rapists, etc).

Comment: How many characters in the Bible sleep with their granddaughters? Every kind of sin is definitely not represented (nor is that surprising)

Comment: Many sins are not mentioned because they do not have a specific reference to the needed story.

Comment: "and as far as I know in later sources" Do you mean to include Midrashim that attribute homosexual behavior to various characters or are you only seeking explicit examples in the text?

Comment: U. Man, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! I look forward to seeing you around!

Comment: Like @DoubleAA mentioned, if you're willing to accept Midrashic interpretations, you don't have to go far to find examples. Offhand, I can think of 2 examples by the time Noach rolls around: [Rashi to Genesis 9:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.9.22?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.9.22.2&lang2=bi) and the Midrash quoted in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8479/).

Comment: Don’t forget that Potifar purchased Yosef for the purpose of having homosexual relations with him. See Sotah 13b.

Comment: IMO, Jewish writers probably felt they didn't need to write about them, since the libraries were already glutted with Roman and Greek literature about their heroes of that persuasion.

Comment: Based on the comments you might want to rephrase your question in two ways: 1. Asking why it is not mentioned explicitly, as there are many interpretations that hint on those sins. 2. You might ask if this is purposeful or accidental as many other sins are not mentioned.

Comment: What about nevuchadnetzar and tsidkiyahu in gemoro shabbos.

Answer (score 9):

In this week’s Torah portion parshat Vayeira Genesis 19,5 it says about the wicked people of Sedom who got destroyed because of their sins:

> וַיִּקְרְא֤וּ אֶל־לוֹט֙ וַיֹּ֣אמְרוּ ל֔וֹ אַיֵּ֧ה הָאֲנָשִׁ֛ים אֲשֶׁר־בָּ֥אוּ אֵלֶ֖יךָ הַלָּ֑יְלָה הוֹצִיאֵ֣ם אֵלֵ֔ינוּ וְנֵדְעָ֖ה אֹתָֽם׃
>   And the men of Sedom called to Lot and they said to him: "where are the men you invited tonight bring them out, so that we should cohabit with them*"

*Rashi:"(ונדעה אתם" - במשכב זכר כמו אשר לא ידעו איש (ב"ר

In fact, that's where the term sodomy comes from.

Also the very parsha that that prohibits homosexuality says that the people of the land of Knaan did such abominations and G-d was disgusted by their actions and threw them out of the land in Leviticus chapter 18:

> ואת זכר לא תשכב משכבי אשה תועבה הוא....אל תטמאו בכל אלה כי בכל אלה נטמאו הגוים אשר אני משלח מפניכם...ותטמא הארץ ואפקד עונה עליה ותקא הארץ את ישביה...כי את כל התועבת האל עשו אנשי הארץ אשר לפניכם ותטמא הארץ
>   Don't practice homosexuallity it is an abomination... Don't do these abominations because the nations which i am throwing out of the land did these impure actions... The land became impure i remembered its sins and the land (of Knaan) regurgitated its inhabitents... For all these abominations they did and the land became contaminated from their sins.

Comment: Also [Shoftim/Judges 19:22](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15827/jewish/Chapter-19.htm#showrashi=true&v=22).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there's also a reference in Melachim to male prostitutes being thrown out of the Mikdash by Yoshiyahu